# Show/hide clear icon inside input field not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have created an input with an icon that clears the input text.

I initially have it set to display:none. 
When you focus on the input, the clear icon appears which is what I want, but when you click the clear icon it disappears and does not clear the input text, but then only reappears when you focus on the input again, which I dont want it to do this, as it should stay visible only until you click out of the input, then it should hide...

So the use case should be:

1. the clear icon should initially be set to hidden (in css or can be jQuery)
2. the clear icon should show when you focus on input
3. the clear icon should hide again, when you click out of the input

My script is not working properly, and I have tried a number of ways to work it out myself but nope, cant figure it out.

```js
$("input")
  .focus(function() {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "enter your email address...");
    $(".material-icons").show();
  })
  .blur(function() {
    $(".material-icons").hide();
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "input here");
    $(".clear-input").click(function() {
      $(this).prev().val("").focus();
    });
  });
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  margin: 20vh;
}

.container {
  border: none;
  width: 248px;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 8px 100px 8px 5px;
  position: relative;
}

input:hover {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

input:focus {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.material-icons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 8px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <input class="type-here" type="text" placeholder="input here" />
    <i class="clear-input material-icons">clear</i>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Move the `$(".clear-input").click` out of the blur event handler

Comment: @charlietfl where am I suppose to put it?

Comment: Before or after the `$('input')` event listeners. Just not inside them

Comment: @charlietfl I moved it outside of the input function, but when I click the clear icon it still hides...can you provide me a snippet. I am not sure why its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change click to mousedown because blur fires sooner than click event and deletes the click event and put click event in focus event.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".material-icons").hide();
  $("input")
  .focus(function() {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "enter your email address...");
    $(".material-icons").show();
    $(".clear-input").mousedown(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).prev().val("");
    });
  })
  .blur(function() {
    $(".material-icons").hide();
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "input here");
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  margin: 20vh;
}

.container {
  border: none;
  width: 248px;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 8px 100px 8px 5px;
  position: relative;
}

input:hover {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

input:focus {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.material-icons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <input class="type-here" type="text" placeholder="input here" />
    <i class="clear-input material-icons">clear</i>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: your code is not resolving my issue....the X should remain visible when in the input and when there is text entered

Comment: What is exactly wrong with the code above ? if you press x it deletes the content. You want the X to still be visible after the click ?

Comment: yes, if that is possible. The x should be hidden initially, remain visible when inside the input, and then hidden when you click outside the input only.

Comment: I added a preventDefault to prevent blur from happening when you click on X. check the edited code.

Comment: that is exactly what I needed. Thank you! By the way, do you know why the display:none is not working to hide the x initially?

Comment: put a !important in front of it because it is also defined inside the other css you added : https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons and has a display value of `inline-block`

Comment: oh, its not displaying the x now with !important. That's okay, I'll work it out. Thanks again.

Comment: You don't have to do it with !important which is inappropriate anyway. I've edited my code again and done that with a line of js `$(".material-icons").hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat inelegant solution:

```
$("input").focus(function() {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "enter your email address...");
    $(".material-icons").show();
});


$('body').click(function(e){
   if ( !$(e.target).is('input') && !$(e.target).is('.material-icons') ) {
     $(".material-icons").hide();
   }
});

$('.clear-input').click(function(){
  $('input').val('')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ju9hqpt/44/

Comment: Cheers for the snippet.